# Simple Function attains a maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $A_1,..,A_n \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be sets with finite measure and let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be real numbers. Consider the simple function $$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \chi_{A_k}$$

where $\chi_A$ is the indicator function of the set $A$. Is it true that $f$ attains a maximum and minimum on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $f$ can only take on finitely many values. Let $b_1,\ldots,b_l$ be the finitely many distinct values that $f$ can take on, i.e. $b_i\neq b_j$ for $i\neq j$, and let also $$B_i=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid f(x)=b_i\}.$$ Then $B_1,\ldots,B_l$ are disjoint and $\bigcup_{i=1}^l B_i =\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$$
f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^l b_i\chi_{B_i},
$$
Now the maximum value of $f$ is simply $\max_{i=1}^l b_i$ and if $i_0$ is index realizing this maximum, i.e.$b_{i_0}=\max_{i=1}^l b_i$, then the maximum is attained for any $x\in B_{i_0}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simple functions acquire finite values on $\mathbb R^n$. So :
$$\min f(x)=\min\{|a_k| :k=1,\dots,n\}$$
$$\max f(x)=\max\{|a_k| :k=1,\dots,n\}$$

Comment: The sets are not necessarily distinct

Comment: You can write the function in its standard form, where $A'_k$ are disjoint, and $\cup A'_k=\mathbb R^n$.
Also, among them there should be a set $A'_{k_0}$ with infinite measure, while $a'_{k_0}=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$f(x)$ takes at most $2^n$ different values..so attains max. and min ...

Comment: Can't be too careful - if a function takes on a finite number of values then it attains a maximum and minimum, right?